# Coefficients of $n^{-k}$ in Stirling's Formula

Tags: number-theory

I wish to find an explicit formula for $c_1,...,c_k$ such that

\begin{equation}
n!= \sqrt{2\pi n} \Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n\bigg(1+\frac{c_1}{n}+\frac{c_2}{n^2}+...+\frac{c_k}{n^k}+O(n^{-k-1})\bigg).
\end{equation}

[This](http://stat.fsu.edu/techreports/M763.pdf) paper gives:

\begin{equation}
a_n=\begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n-1}-\sum_{k=2}^{\frac{n}{2}}a_ka_{n+1-k}, & \text{if $n$ even}.\\
    \frac{1}{n+1}a_{n-1}-\sum_{k=2}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}a_ka_{n+1-k}-\frac{1}{2}a_{(n+1)/2}^2, & \text{if $n$ odd}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Which is then multiplied by a double factorial to give:

\begin{equation}
n!= \sqrt{2\pi n} \Big(\frac{n}{e}\Big)^n\bigg(1+\frac{3a_3}{n}+\frac{3*5*a_5}{n^2}+\frac{3*5*7*a_7}{n^3}+\ldots\bigg).
\end{equation}

Is this the best equation out there at the moment for $n!$? Thanks!

Comment: of course you should also troll any literature related to the gamma function

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's formula can be derived applying the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to $\ln n! = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \ln k$, giving an asymptotic formula (the series doesn't converge, but the error is less than the first term left out). The sum is for a given $s$:
$$
\ln n! \approx \ln \sqrt{2 \pi} + (n + 1 / 2) \ln n - n
                 - \sum_{1 \le k \le s}
               \frac{B_{2 k}}{(2 k - 1) 2 k} n^{- 2 k - 1}
$$
Here $B_k$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). Take the exponential of this, and expand the exponential of the series as a series...

Comment: Will this give the same results? I thought this to be true but heard off someone the series differed slightly.

Comment: In Knopp's book "The theory and application and infinite series" it says:

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{log}(n!)=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\mathrm{log}(n)-m+\mathrm{log}(\sqrt{2\pi})+\frac{B_2}{1*2}\frac{1}{n}+\frac{B_4}{3*4}\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots+\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k-1)2k}\frac{1}{n^{2k-1}}-(2k)!\int_n^{\infty}\frac{P_{2k+1}(x)}{x^{2k+1}}{d}x.
\end{equation}

Which gives:

\begin{equation}
n!=\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}\mathrm{exp}\left(\frac{B_2}{1*2}\frac{1}{n}+\frac{B_4}{3*4}\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots+\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k-1)2k}\frac{1}{n^{2k-1}}+\frac{A_n}{n^{2k}}\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: @user66411, You are right. Thanks for the correction!